# Trunk Group in Aruba Switches

Tags: switch, trunk, aruba

Please help to clarify a doubt I have.

I need to configure a Aruba JL357A 2540-48G-PoE+-4SFP+ Switch that will be connected with 4 other switches using the SFP ports. So each port will be set to operate in trunk mode.

- Port 49 - sw1
- Port 50 - sw2
- Port 51 - sw3
- Port 52 - sw4

That kind of switch model, I need to create a Trk Group. All the trunks will have the same VLANs.

Can I create a single trunk group (Trk1) and use it in all uplink ports? Or each port has to have its own trunk group (for example: port 49 – trk1, port 50 – trk2, and so on). Even if all the trk group will have the same VLANs?

Something like this

VLAN 100 to 200

- Port 49 – trk1
- Port 50 – trk1
- Port 51 – trk1
- Port 52 – trk1

OR the correct would be

VLAN 100 to 200

- Port 49 – trk1
- Port 50 – trk2
- Port 51 – trk3
- Port 52 – trk4

and all the Trk's with the same VLANs?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a different trunk ID for all trunk that go to different physical switch

The reason behind is that the ID is used if you plug multiple cable for the LAG creation. So technically in your case, as all cable go to different switch, it would be a logic error to have a 4 port trunk that are defined in a LAG, but to different switch.

Comment: That's what I thought. I will go for different ID for each trunk. Thank you.